# Problem to write .csv file using R in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, directory, r

I just installed,I have done some mathematical calculation successfully with R.
Then I try the following,

```
> var1 <- 1:5
> var2 <- (1:5) / 10
> var3 <- c("R", "and", "Data Mining", "Examples", "Case Studies")
> df1 <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
> names(df1) <- c("VariableInt", "VariableReal", "VariableChar")
```

After created `data frame` I tried to write into `sampleData.csv` for that I do the following,

```
> write.csv(df1, "./data/sampleData.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

I got [ERROR]response as,

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
cannot open file './data/samplData.csv': No such file or directory
>
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I run this code in terminal.

Problem cause in directory.

when I do,

```
> getwd()
```

got response as,

```
[1] "/home/arul"
```

But in that directory there is no `r` package. 
I cant find where my R is placed, I used `apt-get install -y r-base`, so how do I set path as installed R ?

**EDIT 1**

I create folder `data` in current directory `/home/arul` as taken by R and then I tried to write csv,

```
> write.csv(df1, "./data/sampleData.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

Now I got permission problem,

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
cannot open file './data/dummyData.csv': Permission denied
```

How to I solve it ?

**EDIT 2**

```
root@arul-PC:/home/arul# stat data
File: ‘data’
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 809h/2057d  Inode: 3147229     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-07-18 12:42:00.057099167 +0530
Modify: 2014-07-18 12:41:59.041099204 +0530
Change: 2014-07-18 12:41:59.041099204 +0530
Birth: -
```

**EDIT 3**

```
> system('whoami', intern=TRUE)
[1] "arul"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems most likely is that `~/data/` doesn't exist. Create that and it should be able to write.

You can do that in R if you like with [`dir.create`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/files2):

```
dir.create("./data", showWarnings=FALSE)
```

---

Thanks to your update we can see that you're running *as root*. That means the directory you created is owned by root and can only be written into by root. Nuke it:

```
sudo rmdir data
```

Then go back to being your user (run `logout` or press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and then recreate the directory. When you `stat` it, the owner/group should both be `arul`.

Comment: Thank you.. Shall you tell me where the package stored in my system ? I used `apt-get install -y r-base` to install R.

Comment: The "permission denied" error seems a very different problem. Are you running R as a different user?

Comment: I am running R with my default Ubuntu user