# Don't have write privileges in Rstudio using Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, permissions, directory, r

I apparently do not have write access in Rstudio (3.3.2) installed on Ubuntu 16.04., i.e. I cannot "write.csv".

Here is the command that does not work:

write.csv(data_frame, file = "file_name.csv", row.names = F)

This does not work when I setwd() to a dropbox directory -- setwd(/home/briankuns/Dropbox/Dropbox/teaching) -- or when I setwd() to the home directory, or when I do not setwd() at all (letting it write.csv go to the default directory). (the Home folder and default directory are maybe the same?) I had no problem writing this particular data frame to csv on my windows computer -- I cannot get it to work on my ubuntu computer.

A couple of times, when trying, I got an error message "permission denied" but mostly, when trying this, I do not get an error message. It looks like R has executed the command, but there is no csv file in the directory I have indicated.

I am probably having the same problem as this question about R on 14.04.

[Problem to write .csv file using R in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499385/problem-to-write-csv-file-using-r-in-14-04)

However, this answer does not help me, as I lack some basic information about how R works on Ubuntu (as I am new to Ubuntu). So my questions are more basic, and I hope they will not be seen as a repetition.

I want to have write-access, and I don't have that now. Is this a result of how R is installed? (as root or as user?) If so, how can find out how R is installed on my system, and change it so that I can have write-access. Or is there a way to change how R runs so that I can have write-access? Or is this a matter of changing permissions in my directories?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact command you are using - including the full pathname of the csv file you are trying to write

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly -- I tried different options, including writing to the home folder...